# How to import an existing PDF file in node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, import

I am working on import routines for node, so far I can import text nodes from a PDF using pdf2json, this works well, but doesn't work on PDF's that are image based and contain no text.

So I downloaded pdf2img, however there are plenty of issues with this module, the one I have now is that after running it, I get a lot of 0 byte png files created, no content and an error message:

```
    /docfire/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:228
        proc.stdin.once('error', cb);
                  ^

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'once' of undefined
        at gm._spawn (/docfire/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:228:15)
        at /docfire/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:140:19
        at series (/docfire/node_modules/array-series/index.js:11:36)
        at gm._preprocess
```

(/docfire/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:177:5)
            at gm.stream (/docfire/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:138:10)
            at convertPdf2Img (/docfire/node_modules/pdf2img/lib/pdf2img.js:93:6)
            at /docfire/node_modules/pdf2img/lib/pdf2img.js:67:9
            at /docfire/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17
            at /docfire/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:122:13
            at _each (/docfire/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:13)

I've tried posting a issue on the GIT site for the module, but it looks like quite a few people are having exactly the same problem and there doesn't seem to be any activity regarding any fixes.

What I would ideally like is a way to extract text and images from a PDF for node.

I'm running on an iMAC running macOS Sierra v10.12.4
With node version 7.8.0, pdf2img 0.2.0, gm 1.23.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try pdf-image npm package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-image

Hope this helps.